# tomcat7 UnsupportedClassVersionError when running with java7

Tags: tomcat7, grails-2.0

problem: when deploying my war to tomcat7 i get the error 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org.MyLibraryClass : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

(this is the error one gets when compiling java with a newer version than the java used when running the code.)

situation, in order:

1. brand new ubuntu 12.04.1 server 64bit minimal, in a virtualbox
2. installed tomcat6
3. tried to deploy my war
4. realized the error, and that i need java7 because ubuntu 12 still comes with outdated java
5. installed oracle java 7 using this guide https://askubuntu.com/questions/197248/java-on-ubuntu-server-12-04

   > ```
   >   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   >   sudo apt-get update
   >   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
   > ```
6. removed tomcat6 and installed tomcat7

   > ```
   >   sudo apt-get remove tomcat6-common
   >   sudo apt-get install tomcat7
   > ```
7. deployed my war to tomcat7
8. started tomcat

   > ```
   >   sudo service tomcat7 start
   > ```
9. checked my app's log file. same error.
10. echo $JAVA_HOME is empty, java -version shows:

    > ```
    >   java version "1.7.0_07"
    >   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
    >   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
    > ```
11. it's a default tomcat7 install, no modification. still i checked the startup scripts and config to make sure no custom java version is specified anywhere. also checked by asking catalina:

> ```
>   ubuntu@ubuntu:/home$ /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh version
>   Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
>   Server built:   Jul 19 2012 03:21:30
>   Server number:  7.0.26.0
>   OS Name:        Linux
>   OS Version:     3.2.0-29-generic
>   Architecture:   amd64
>   JVM Version:    1.7.0_07-b10
>   JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
> ```

now i'm stuck. i don't see how any java code could fail to run on oracle's jre7.

my war is a brand new very basic hello world grails 2.1 app with maven, which has a maven dependency (org.MyLibraryClass) that is compiled with jdk7. that's the one for which i get the error.

in grails i changed BuildConfig.groovy to have 1.7 instead of 1.6:

> ```
>   grails.project.target.level = 1.7
>   grails.project.source.level = 1.7
> ```

then did a grails clean, rebuild, war, redeploy. no change.

any idea what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

Typical error when compiling code with Java7 and running it under Java6.

Answer (score 0):

The critical line in your query is this one I think:

```
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

I think it may be triggering the inheritance of OpenJDK still in the system there. What you want to do is instead try tomcat from your own environment.

Login as your normal user

```
java -version
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
```

and check. You should also login as a clean user, root or elsewhere and check java -version to check.

If all else fails, go to /etc/profile and make sure path to Oracle's Java/bin directory is the very first thing in the PATH variable for the environment.

Comment: no luck. i modified /etc/profile and added as first non-comment line: 
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:$PATH 
then reloaded it with 
. /etc/profile
still getting the same error when running it as 
sudo service tomcat7 start

Comment: System service would not read /etc/profile. Edit startup.sh and put a debug line for  java -version  in there to print to the console or file and check.

Comment: i also tried to execute /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh as standard user (named ubuntu), but that caused more problems. too much to add to this tiny commend field. in short, permission problems with folders owned by user tomcat7. plus that would not be a bootsafe setup. nevertheless i tried but failed.

Comment: It is easy enough to install a new tomcat as a user. Create a temporary directory say /home/user/tmp.  Download the .tar.gz version of tomcat and put it in there. Put your webapp in there and try it.  That way you run it all inside the user context and it is easy for you to debug.

Comment: thanks for your help guys. i followed unixrules suggestion and installed a local version. and was finally able to bring that up. i'll see about making it boot-safe next. so it counts as a workaround - i don't know what the cause is for the main service installation.

Comment: The other thing you can look at is also to try the alternatives command.   " alternatives --display java "   and check and then set it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem just now,but now it's solved.

Please check this symbolic

> /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

it's default link is open-jdk, reset the correct jdk dirctory.

good luck!